# Cypress TestRunner via "cypress.open" works locally but does not work on Windows Server 2008

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, windows-server-2008-r2, cypress

I am using Cypress testing framework JS API and trying to host it on Windows Server 2008.  When I execute a Javascript command "cypress.open" locally on Windows 10 laptop, the TestRunner window opens up and I can run manually run tests.

But the same does not work on Windows Server 2008.  No error is being reported.  Has this something to do with any kind of security aspect related to Windows Server 2008?  Can anyone please shed any light on what might be happening here.

I have installed cypress using npm on the server.

```
npm install cypress
```

Installing it at C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local

Here is the Javascript code to open the cypress test runner.

```
Var cypress = require(‘cypress’);
module.exports = function(callback)
{
cypress.open({
project:  ‘./node_modules/.bin’
});
callback(null,”Opening cypress”);
};
```

I am using ASP.NET Core to run the node module.  The C# code is here:

```
public asynchronous Task<IActionResult> OpenTests()
{
  Var data = await  _nodeservices.InvokeAsync<string>(“Scripts/OpenTests.js”);
return ok(data);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify you meet the [System requirements](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#System-requirements)